# rsync files to a kubernetes pod

Tags: rsync, kubernetes

I need to rsync a file tree to a specific pod in a kubernetes cluster. It seems it should be possible if only one can convince rsync that kubectl acts sort of like rsh. Something like:

```
rsync --rsh='kubectl exec -i podname -- ' -r foo x:/tmp
```

... except that this runs into problems with x since rsync assumes a hostname is needed:

```
exec: "x": executable file not found in $PATH
```

I can not seem to find a method to help rsync construct the rsh command. Is there a way to do this? Or some other method by which relatively efficient file transfer can be achieved over a pipe?

(I am aware of `gcloud compute copy-files`, but it can only be used onto the node?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I wrote a Python script to act as a [receiver of tar files.](https://github.com/bittrance/docker-shinken/blob/master/catcher.py)
 You can do thus:

```
tar cf - . | kubectl exec shinken -i catcher -v /etc/shinken/custom_configs
```

Note that this only works if you cluster nodes are kubernetes 1.1 or later.

Answer (score 62):

To `rsync` to a Pod I use the following helper.

```
pod=$1;shift;kubectl exec -i $pod -- "$@"
```

I put this in a file called "rsync-helper.sh" and then run the `rsync` like so.

```
rsync -av --progress --stats -e './rsync-helper.sh' source-dir/ thePodName:/tmp/dest-dir
```

If you'd like a simple script that wraps this all up, save this as `krsync`.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$KRSYNC_STARTED" ]; then
    export KRSYNC_STARTED=true
    exec rsync --blocking-io --rsh "$0" $@
fi

# Running as --rsh
namespace=''
pod=$1
shift

# If user uses pod@namespace, rsync passes args as: {us} -l pod namespace ...
if [ "X$pod" = "X-l" ]; then
    pod=$1
    shift
    namespace="-n $1"
    shift
fi

exec kubectl $namespace exec -i $pod -- "$@"
```

Then you can use `krsync` where you would normally rsync.

```
krsync -av --progress --stats src-dir/ pod:/dest-dir
```

You can also set the namespace.

```
krsync -av --progress --stats src-dir/ pod@namespace:/dest-dir
```

**NOTE:** The Pod must have the `rsync` executable installed for this to work.

Comment: This script works perfectly!

Comment: Works perfectly indeed, the `--rsh` part is not trivial at all to understand. Downside is not using tar

Comment: hats off to you, sir. This is a very elegant script.

Comment: Error on my Mac OS: rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-52/rsync/compat.c(61) [sender=2.6.9]
command terminated with exit code 126

Comment: Thank you for the script. I am new to k8s and was trying to migrate my old server. Saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Just helped me sync 21 gigs of data. I wrote a blog post describing how it can be used in disaster recovery with a link back here: https://vhs.codeberg.page/post/recover-files-kubernetes-persistent-volume/

Comment: Thanks so much for the script which works very well. Could you please provide some explanation about how it works? It is not trivial to understand.

Comment: protocol incompatibility is an error raised by not having rsync binary on the pod

Comment: high-level explanation: `krsync` runs `exec rsync --blocking-io --rsh` which runs itself again. But on this second run, `KRSYNC_STARTED` is set, so the script continues to `exec kubectl` which runs the server-side rsync receiver. The client-side rsync process that started the first time, sends over the data.

Comment: AMAZING!  But I think the first `rsync` line should have quotes around `$@` as in`exec rsync --blocking-io --rsh "$0" "$@"`

Answer (score 2):

If the `tar` binary is available on the container, you can transfer files using the new [`cp` command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#cp).

Though possibly not as efficient as rsync.

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner, just edit to you names and paths:

```
p_user=$USER;p_name=$POD_NAME; rsync -avurP --blocking-io --rsync-path= --rsh="$(which kubectl) exec $p_name -i -- " /home/$USER/target_dir rsync:/home/$p_user/
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @karl-bunch was perfect. For those who prefer using `tar` this is how I use it:

```sh
tar -cvz -C /orig-dir . | kubectl exec -ti podname -- sh -c 'cd /var/www && tar -xzv'
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem today. I had to sync files from the pod to my local machine.

My solution for this was this rsync command

```
rsync -aOv --blocking-io --rsync-path="/some/path/on/pod" --rsh="kubectl exec somePod -c someContainer -i -- " rsync:"/some/path/on/pod /some/local/path
```

Comment: the double-quotes are unbalanced: should I add one? of remove the `rsync:"` quote?

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported, but there is an issue for adding support which you can +1 or even contribute to:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/18007#issuecomment-164797262